# CarrierWave MiniMagick resizing gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

I am using CarrierWave with MiniMagick to resize and uploaded file. I have the version directive in my uploader

```
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
  end
```

But when I upload the file, the operation fails. The exception I am getting is

```
No such file or directory - identify -ping /var/folders/Au/AuBTXIH8HzCAhKdy0jvi+k+++TI/-Tmp-/mini_magick20120906-64039-1gx1ptu.jpg
```

The name of the file I am uploading is hat.jpg. The `/var/folders/Au/AuBTXIH8HzCAhKdy0jvi+k+++TI/-Tmp-/` directory does exist, but when I do the upload I do not see the file in question being created.

Any suggestions as to what the problem may be?

**Edit**: I have found that the specific issue is that MiniMagick is spawning a command to run `identify`, and the identify command is not being found. But it is on my system at `/usr/local/bin/identify` --it was installed as part of ImageMagick.For some reason MiniMagick is not picking it up.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: ImageMagick is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that the problem was with my RubyMine IDE, not my application or ImageMagick or MiniMagick.

It seems when the RubyMine IDE is launched (by double-clicking the RubyMine icon) it does not inherit the PATH that would exist for a terminal session. Therefore `/usr/local/bin/` was not in my server path when I launched the rails server from within RubyMine.

I am able to run my application successfully when launching the server from the command line. I also found that if I launch RubyMine from the command line (using `open -a RubyMine`), then the terminal session is inherited and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

add to the TOP of your /etc/paths:

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

This will tell the mac OS that new shells should have this variable.
I say to add to the top because with homebrew, you are often adding paths that override built in mac applications